# Access windows symbolic link from linux cifs

Tags: raspberry-pi, symlink, raspbian, cifs

I have created symbolic link of the mapped drive (DOS share) on Windows 7 computer 200.90.12.25. The symbolic link was created using mklink command. Trying to access this from Linux (Raspberry PI) using CIFS command, I get `mount error(5): Input/output error`. CIFS command and dmesg attached below.

I cannot access the DOS share from Linux because of NETBEUI. Line diagram shown below for reference.

[image]

**CIFS command**

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=username,guest,vers=2.0 //200.90.12.25/DOSA /home/pi/myNAS/myShare
```

**dmesg** (also on the Linux client)

```
[1027098.510573] FS-Cache: Duplicate cookie detected
[1027098.510583] FS-Cache: O-cookie c=c6d9fc6c [p=33027f2d fl=222 nc=2 na=1]
[1027098.510588] FS-Cache: O-cookie d=e8ce4e52 n=203d934d
[1027098.510592] FS-Cache: O-key=[8] '020001bd0a090c12'
[1027098.510606] FS-Cache: N-cookie c=435e27ec [p=33027f2d fl=2 nc=0 na=1]
[1027098.510611] FS-Cache: N-cookie d=e8ce4e52 n=9f19c9a0
[1027098.510614] FS-Cache: N-key=[8] '020001bd0a090c12'
[1027098.515854] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -5
```

As per the suggested comments, i have tried below commands. I got the same `mount error(5): Input/output error`

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=username,guest,vers=2.1,mfsymlinks //200.90.12.25/DOSA /home/pi/myNAS/myShare
```

mount.cifs

```
sudo mount.cifs //200.90.12.25/DOSA /home/pi/myNAS/myShare -o username=username,guest,domain=domain,mfsymlinks
```

any alternative solution much appreciated.

Comment: 200.90.12.25 is the windows 7 computer, created a symbolic link (DOSA) of mapped drive (DOS Share), After typing cifs mount , i typed dmesg (the message displayed above).

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but I'll wait and see what others say

Comment: Didn't see it before but to define a user you should use the `username` key.
Try `username=username` rather than `user=username`

Comment: Changing from user to username did not help me. I am getting same error.

Comment: If any additional details required from my end please let me know.

Comment: @BhuvanKumar Which version of SAMBA is your server running ? Perhaps you should use the `mfsymlinks` option as discussed here [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1337257/clients-cant-create-symlinks-on-samba-share?answertab=votes#tab-top) ? And also you should try to use the `mount.cifs` utility which is part of the `cifs-utils` package. See here [link](https://www.putorius.net/mount-windows-share-linux.html) and here [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468914/ubuntu-14-04-how-do-you-use-mount-cifs-mount-nfs-they-are-not-in-the-reposit). Let me know.

Comment: smbclient --version - `4.9.5-Debian`, I tried the option `mfsymlinks` with `vers=2.0` and `vers=2.1`, i got `mount error(5): Input/output error`, in `vers=3.0` I got `mount error(95) Operation not supported`. I have tried `mount.cifs` I got the same `mount error(5): Input/output error`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please clarify your question just a bit more, you said a windows symlink is what you are trying to mount?  Was this created using the mklink command on windows?  I'm not sure if it would be possible to use a windows lnk file as a location to mount if that is what you are referring to attempting to mount.  You might consider something like what the above poster said:

`sudo mount -t cifs -o username=username,guest,vers=2.1,mfsymlinks //200.90.12.25/DOSA /home/pi/myNAS/myShare`

According to the man page:

`mfsymlinks                Enable support for Minshall+French symlinks (see http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/UNIX_Extensions#Minshall.2BFrench_symlinks).  This  option  is  ignored when specified together with the sfu option. Minshall+French symlinks are used even if the  server  supports  the CIFS Unix Extensions.`

Possible alternative:
I know this sounds like a horrid suggestion, but if you could put a ftpd on the dos box you could use this fuse extension to mount that as a writable filesystem.  I have included a link to the sourceforge page below.

[Curl FTP Filesystem](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Yes, I had created the symbolic using `mklink` command. After using `mfsymlinks` i got the same `mount error(5): Input/output error`, I tried the `curlftpfs`. the command i used was `sudo curlftpfs //200.90.12.25/DOSA myDOSA/`, I got `Error connecting to FTP`. Let me know if i am using the command properly..

Answer (score -1):

Have a look to the Microsoft documentation:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/josebda/windows-server-2012-r2-which-version-of-the-smb-protocol-smb-1-0-smb-2-0-smb-2-1-smb-3-0-or-smb-3-02-are-you-using

On Windows 7 you should use CIFS/SMB 2.1

I suggest you try this:

`sudo mount -t cifs -o username=username,guest,vers=2.1 //200.90.12.25/DOSA /home/pi/myNAS/myShare`

This seems to work for some people like mentioned here:
https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues/2373

Comment: I tried 2.1 also, I am getting same error.